# Creating an instance of a class to call static methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, static, instance

I recently came across some code which looks something like this,

```
class MyClass {
  private static instance: MyClass;
  private myString: string;

  public static Instance(myString) {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = new this(myString);
    }
    return this.instance;
  }
  private constructor(myString: string) {
    this.myString = myString;
  }
  public getMyString() {
    console.log(this.myString);
  }
}
```

My question is, what is the need to do something like this? Why would a person create an instance like this, instead of creating an instance of the class 'the normal way'.

What is the benefit of doing thing like this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Accessing `this.myString` within a static method looks like an error to me

Comment: yeah sorry made a mistake while copying

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This pattern is used to ensure that a class has only one instance: the constructor is private, so it cannot be used from the outside of the class.

Regarding this particular implementation, I would suggest a couple of fixes:

- `this.instance` in the static method should be `MyClass.instance` instead
- in the following call `new this(myString)`, `myString` will be `undefined` because non static variables cannot be referenced from the static context
- there is no way to set `myString`
- `public static Instance { ... }` should be a static method instead: `public static instance() { ... }`

Comment: `Instance` should also be a function